# Is it safe to only use width on a fluid retina <img> tag

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, fluid-layout

The standard solution to get an `<img>` tag to display well on a retina display is to double the image size and put the original `width=` and `height=` attributes on the tag to squish it down to size.

I'm working on a fluid layout where I have various `img { min-width: xx%; }` styles in media queries.  The problem is that when I have the `height=` attribute on the `<img>` but the `max-width` is in effect, the image aspect ratio becomes distorted because the height is still respected.

Is there any reason the hi-res retina solution won't work with only a `width=` attribute?

That way the img height is automatically calculated.  It seems to work but I haven't been able to find any other information about only using the `width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
img { 
min-width: xx%; 
height: auto;
}
```

in your CSS?

Comment: Huh, I guess that's pretty much what I'm doing by excluding the `height` attribute on the element.  Thanks for reminding me of this.